# Convert a column of lists into a regular column in a data.frame?

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, sapply

Here is a data.frame where the second column is a column of lists (note there is also a `NULL`).

How can we convert each list into a regular element so the column is like any other character class column? (the `NULL` can be `NA`)

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), Country = list(Country = "Canada", 
    Country = "Germany", Country = "France", Country = "Germany", 
    Country = "Mexico", Country = "Germany", Country = "Germany", 
    Country = "Canada", NULL, Country = "Germany", Country = "Mexico", 
    Country = "Canada", Country = "Mexico", Country = "Germany", 
    Country = "Canada", Country = "United States of America", 
    Country = "Canada", Country = "Mexico", Country = "Canada", 
    Country = "Germany")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Note

```
df %>% sapply(class)
     Year   Country 
"integer"    "list"
```

Desired result:

- Same data but

```
df %>% sapply(class)
     Year   Country 
"integer"    "character"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an approach using a function over your `df` data:

```
myfun <- function(x)
{
  if(is.null(x)) 
    {y <- NA} 
  else
  {
    y <- x[[1]]
  }
  return(y)
}
#Apply  
df$Newvar <- as.vector(do.call(rbind,lapply(df$Country,myfun)))
```

Output:

```
   Year                  Country                   Newvar
1  2014                   Canada                   Canada
2  2014                  Germany                  Germany
3  2014                   France                   France
4  2014                  Germany                  Germany
5  2014                   Mexico                   Mexico
6  2014                  Germany                  Germany
7  2014                  Germany                  Germany
8  2014                   Canada                   Canada
9  2014                     NULL                     <NA>
10 2014                  Germany                  Germany
11 2014                   Mexico                   Mexico
12 2014                   Canada                   Canada
13 2014                   Mexico                   Mexico
14 2014                  Germany                  Germany
15 2013                   Canada                   Canada
16 2014 United States of America United States of America
17 2014                   Canada                   Canada
18 2014                   Mexico                   Mexico
19 2014                   Canada                   Canada
20 2014                  Germany                  Germany
```

And some checks:

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Year   : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ Country:List of 20
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "France"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "Mexico"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$        : NULL
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "Mexico"
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$ Country: chr "Mexico"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$ Country: chr "United States of America"
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$ Country: chr "Mexico"
  ..$ Country: chr "Canada"
  ..$ Country: chr "Germany"
 $ Newvar : chr  "Canada" "Germany" "France" "Germany" ...
```

Where `Newvar` is not a list now.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
df$Country <- sapply(df$Country, function(x) if (length(x)) x else NA)
```

Another:

```
df$Country[lengths(df$Country) == 0] <- list(NA)
df$Country <- as.vector(df$Country)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to keep it more aligned with dplyr's `mutate`.

```
  df2 = df %>% 
  mutate(NewCountry = if_else(
    sapply(df$Country, is.null), 
    "MISSING", 
    as.character(df$Country))
  )

> sapply(df2, class)
       Year     Country  NewCountry 
  "integer"      "list" "character"
```